# Flatten a document in document db

Tags: database, azure, document, azure-cosmosdb

I have a document in document db that has a property that is an array of an object. I would like to flatten it and get a single property in all the objects in terms of an array.

eg:

```
{
    "name" : "blah",
    "address" : [
        {
           "type" : "home",
           "location" : "123 st"
        },
        {
           "type" : "work",
           "location" : "321 st"
        }
    ]
}
```

-> What I want

```
[
    {
       "name" : "blah",
       "locations" : [ "123 st", "321 st" ]
    }
```

]

Comment: Have you looked at the `JOIN` operator in the SQL syntax?

Comment: @DavidMakogon Yeah looked into that JOIN will create separate record for each of the value in the array.

Answer (score 1):

You could try to define and use [User-defined function](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/documentdb/documentdb-programming#a-idudfauser-defined-functions) to extract `locations` info.

[image]

And then you could call this User-defined function from inside your query.

[image]

Comment: Hmm didn't think of this will try using this process thanks a lot.

Comment: Just realized don't think I can use this. Thats because the flattening is to be done in Azure Search Index Data Source. So the function defined in DocumentDb wouldn't be able to be used there unless I can define the same UDF in Azure Search

Comment: You can supply the UDF to a query to the data source in Azure Search.